# Converting a spark dataframe that contains Vector as a feature into CSV file

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to convert a spark dataframe into a CSV file.

The problem is that one of the features is a Vector structure and I am not sure how to deal with it. I got this dataframe as a result of a `lda.transform()` function for Latent Dirichlet Allocation. I am using `spark.ml` library.

The general `df.coalesce(1).write.option("header", true).csv("<file output path>")` that I usually use doesn't work in this case.

This is how the dataframe looks like:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [label: bigint, topicDistribution: vector]

scala> df_new.show
+-----+--------------------+
|label|   topicDistribution|
+-----+--------------------+
|    0|[6.71576085454879...|
|    1|[5.74898984641732...|
|    2|[1.50297841245588...|
|    3|[3.83251655971072...|
|    4|[8.62396858027641...|
|    5|[1.54900186503601...|
|    6|[1.61493761327978...|
|    7|[9.36938609746372...|
|    8|[1.34332824038935...|
|    9|[1.09991943420077...|
|   10|[1.29739085981008...|
|   11|[8.92839698024594...|
|   12|[4.12414455173398...|
|   13|[1.56497583389755...|
|   14|[1.80725990261967...|
|   15|[1.80725990261967...|
|   16|[9.36938609746372...|
|   17|[1.53335069918914...|
|   18|[1.51801264939744...|
|   19|[7.15931646362877...|
+-----+--------------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

I don't need to expand these arrays into a separate features, I just need to convert it as it is. 
How can I convert this into a CSV file?

Comment: May I ask why `df.coalesce(1).write.option("header", true).csv("<file output path>")` is not working? What is the error?

Comment: `type Vector is not supported...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I managed to do it using

```
df.map { row => (row.getAs[Long]("label"), "[" + row.getAs[org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector("topicDistribution").toArray.mkString(",") + "]") }
```

It works but this is a bad hack. I am sure there must be a better way but it will do for now.

Answer (score 0):

Take into account that using `coalesce(1)` will affect the way the previous steps n the `DataFrame` will be performed. Passing only 1 partition as parameter for the `coalesce` will greatly reduce the parallelism and hence you may face memory errors.

Please, try `repartition` instead, since this will not affect the parallelism of previous operations and you will get a similar result (i.e. only one csv being written).

It would be something like:

```
df.repartition(1).write.option("header", true).csv("<file output path>")
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I will do it in the future with `repartition`. But type vector isn't supported in CSV conversion so I need to do some workaround.

Comment: Why don't you map your column into a String one? Something like `df_new.map(<function_that_converts_vector_column_to_string>)`. That way, the resulting DataFrame will have a string, which is managed by the CSV library. Also that would make it possible to control the string representation you want to use. If you need an specific example let me know and I will create a new answer with the details.

Comment: At the end I managed to do it using `df.map { row => (row.getAs[Long]("label"), "[" + row.getAs[org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector]("topicDistribution").toArray.mkString(",") + "]") } `. It works but this is a bad hack. I am sure there must be a better way but it will do for now. Thanks for your inputs, it was helpful!